# Publish to Artifactory from Bamboo 6

Tags: artifactory, bamboo

I am using Bamboo `6.0.3 build 60004` and I installed the version `2.1.0` of the [official Artifactory plugin for Bamboo](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bamboo+Artifactory+Plug-in).

The `build.gradle` of the project looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
...
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}

afterEvaluate {
    androidJavadocs.classpath += files(android.libraryVariants.collect { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.classpath.files
    })
}

publishing {
    publications {
        android.buildTypes.all { variant ->
            "${variant.name}Aar"(MavenPublication) {
                // set values from Android manifest file
                groupId group
                version version
                if (variant.name == "release") {
                    artifactId project.getName()
                }
                else {
                    artifactId "${project.getName()}-${variant.name}"
                }

                artifact "$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-${variant.name}-${version}.aar"
                artifact androidJavadocsJar

                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                    // List all compile dependencies and write to POM
                    configurations.compile.getAllDependencies().each { Dependency dep ->
                        if (dep.group == null || dep.version == null || dep.name == null || dep.name == "unspecified")
                            return // ignore invalid dependencies

                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dep.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dep.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dep.version)

                        if (!dep.transitive) {
                            // If this dependency is transitive, we should force exclude all its dependencies them from the POM
                            def exclusionNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions').appendNode('exclusion')
                            exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', '*')
                            exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', '*')
                        } else if (!dep.properties.excludeRules.empty) {
                            // Otherwise add specified exclude rules
                            def exclusionNode = dependencyNode.appendNode('exclusions').appendNode('exclusion')
                            dep.properties.excludeRules.each { ExcludeRule rule ->
                                exclusionNode.appendNode('groupId', rule.group ?: '*')
                                exclusionNode.appendNode('artifactId', rule.module ?: '*')
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def libraryGroupId = group
def libraryVersion = version

artifactory {
    contextUrl = '<artifactory_url>'

    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = '<repoKey>'

            username = artifactory_username
            password = artifactory_password
        }
        defaults {
            android.buildTypes.all { variant ->
                publications("${variant.name}Aar")
                publishArtifacts = true
            }

            properties = ['qa.level': 'basic', 'dev.team': 'core']
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the command `gradle build assembleRelease artifactoryPublish` on my laptop, it uploads in the Artifactory repo an `aar` and a `pom` file.

I tried using the `Artifactory Deployment` task in the deployment project that runs after a build task that does `gradle build assembleRelease` (so the same but without the publishing to artifactory), but it instead publishes only the aar file and the directory structure in artifactory doesn't look the same (it does not breakdown the package name by subfolder). How to achieve the same with Bamboo?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use JFrog, we use Nexus, but it looks like that Deployment Project task in the plugin is designed just to take the shared/published artifacts from the build plan the Deployment Project is dependent on and upload those to Artifactory.  So for your first problem, the POM not being uploaded, is the POM a shared artifact in the source build plan feeding the Deployment Project?  So you have two shared artifacts in that build plan, the archive AAR file and the POM?

For your second problem, it may depend on how you define the path to shared artifact in source build plan.  It doesn't look like the deployment task gives you any options about where to write the artifact to in artifactory.  However, I notice the normal build plan task uses a JSON file descriptor where you have more control:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+File+Specs

So I wonder if you would have more flexibility if you published your artifact from the feeding normal Build Plan rather than from the Deployment Project, and just downloaded the artifact from artifactory at the beginning of your Deployment Project tasks for that environment.

Not a solution really - just a bunch of things to look at that might help.

Comment: yes, I saw the File Specs before, but not much examples on how it could help in doing what I want. I don't mind using it, but how? also, it needs to be automatic, so setting things like groupId/artifactId can be done for each project, but the version needs to be taken from the AAR file itself

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Bamboo Artifacotry plugin official page](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bamboo+Artifactory+Plug-in) there is no plugin yet for Bamboo 6.0 (but for Bamboo 5.15).
However if you use a gradle task to publish, the Bamboo plugin is not used.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. I am asking about how to publish both the `aar` file and the `pom` files using the plugin just like when I do without the plugin. I know it's two different thing, but I was expecting the same result using either, but that is not the case

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an update available for versions 6+ for Bamboo Server located here:
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.jfrog.bamboo.bamboo-artifactory-plugin/server/overview

However, I am trying it now with Atlassian Bamboo version 6.3.2 build 60307 and keep getting this error:

```
  Could not execute task  no Plugin with key 'org.jfrog.bamboo.bamboo-
   artifactory-plugin:artifactoryGenericResolveTask' is installed.
```

Tried adding it as an executable as documented here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Bamboo%20Artifactory%20Plug-in

But still receiving the error. So trying again using the spec file it recommends just using generic resolve task but still no luck.

Comment: Yes I am trying with the same plugin, but I can't figure out how to make it work like I want. On a side note, this is not really an answer

Comment: Looks comparable to many of the answers on stack overflow but thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I meant, you are only explaining your problems with the plugin, so it looks more like a question than an answer. We usually write this as comments on the question, or you would create a totally new question for it